# Geforce 820M Black screen after installing Legacy Drivers

Tags: nvidia, gpu, xserver

is there any way to make Nvidia 820m working in ubuntu? I tried all versions from 14.04 and ending with 20.04. I tried drivers starting with 340xx and ending with 390xx. None are working. For example i installed driver without DKMS, it installed successfully but after i wrote `sudo service gdm start` or lightdm. It frezes on black screen and if i hard reboot my laptop. All i get is a black screen after an ubuntu logo, But if i press Ctrl Alt Fxx and write startx, Desktop loads but no gpu acceleration and xconfig error in nvidia x server. I made it working somehow on ubuntu 20.04 340xx but it was only once, after i reinstalled ubuntu, and did the same thing it black screens, some kind of magic.

Comment: After installing several drivers, there may be a cleanup issue of old drivers that may keep things from working.  A fresh install takes the "nomodeset" on the linux line in grub the first boot, to allow the proprietary Nvidia drivers to be installed, then reboot, and the nomodeset is no longer needed.

Comment: So what should i write in Grub?

Comment: Standard Nvidia instructions:  edit the Grub menu (type E) use the arrow keys to move to the line starting with "linux" and add the word nomodeset at the existing words "quiet splash".  Boot that, and add your proprietary drivers. reboot.

Comment: Can i install anything higher than 340xx?

Comment: Search this site for 820m.  I see someone who got the nvidia-driver-390 installed and working better than the 340.

Comment: I see nmath found a link for the 430 driver which supports the 820m at https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149138/en-us

Comment: Thanks for nomodeset. It works perfectly with 340xx and gde (not working on lightdm idk why). About 430xx. 820m is a legacy GPU that supports only legacy driver. 430 has support for 800 series, but only 840 and higher. They simply forgot to remove it from there or something, but i can tell that drivers higher than 390xx has no 820m ID inside. We discussed that with Nmath

Comment: Hey i did it. I made it working. 390xx 820m fully accelerated. But it works only in gdm, lightdm black screen

Answer (score 1):

If anyone having problems with 820m PLEASE Follow this

820m IS A LEGACY gpu with LEGACY drivers ONLY
Anything higher than 390xx will not work!!!

There is 420xx, 450xx drivers and even 455xx drivers. But they dont have 820m ID inside, Nvidia simply forgot to remove 820m from their support list. If you try to install anything higher than 390xx, you will get 820m is not supported warning!

820m works best on GDM. Distros on lightdm (deepin, elementary) wont work (please edit me if i am wrong)

To install 390xx you have to boot using `nomodeset` (go to grub and press E, find `quiet splash` and replace it with `nomodeset`). Press Ctrl + Alt + F(any number from 1 to 6) and enter

`sudo service gdm stop`

`sudo apt install nvidia-340`

After an install boot to ubuntu WITHOUT nomodeset, login and find Nvidia in Application Menu. If it works without errors and warnings. You can install 390xx. Add Graphics repo

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`

It will take long time but it will successfully install.
Enjoy!!